# Merge in local, base or other?

Tags: merge, mercurial

I have a project in which I've set up a bitbucket repo using mercurial.
We're actually 3 to work on it, so we're using branches.

When we did merges, we did them quite randomly so many times it failed.

Actually, I'm using Meld, and I don't really know in "which" part of the repo I have to choose which part of the source code I want to merge.

So, when I do merge, where should I do it ?
I'm not really sure if I have to do it on local, base or other, even though I know local corresponds to my last modifications, other corresponds to the last modifications of the branch I want to merge, and well, actually I'm not really sure about what is other ...

Comment: I don't think it's very clear what your problem is here, could you maybe give an example using a specific file of what the problem is? Base is the common ancestor to the file that is different in local (working directory) and other (the branch changeset you're trying to merge into local).

Comment: Well, for example I'm in branch A, when I do hg merge B, it opens meld for each file where there's conflicts, and highlights everything that is different. But the problem is that I'm not sure in which side I must move the differences.
For example if in my branch A, in one file I've got void foo() (in local), and on the other branch B, I've got void foo(int bar) (so in "other" if i'm right), and I want to keep the "void foo()", where should I move the differences ?

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for help in how to use Meld specifically? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with it. I'm sorry if you know the following already, I'm just not sure where your knowledge is at right now. When you merge from B into A what's happening is you're just copying text from B into the on disk file in your working copy of A. So if you don't want the changes from B then you just leave your working copy as is.

Comment: No problem, still thanks for the help. I'm not really sure if meld is the problem, I thought kdiff or the other software were working the same way. As for my knowledge, basically I only do simple pushes, pulls, branches and when it works, merges.

Answer (score 2):

On careful review, I have found it out. You want to merge into `local`
Please correct me if I'm wrong but I am pretty sure after doing some tests

### Local

The correct place to merge change to. The local files that will result from the merge. This will likely contain a mix of some auto-merged lines already.

### Base

Where you are merging into.

### Other

The merges you're pulling

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the "right" answer, but when in doubt, I make them ALL match by making them look ALL merged 'correctly' (sometimes I have to discuss with my coworkers what the 'correct' look is based on their changes).

By doing this, I ensure the merge will be successful because meld cannot and will not actually change upstream data in mercurial. So there's no downside. For the life of me I also cannot tell which pane to merge into (mostly because the term 'base vs local' is ambiguous). So this is kind of an odd way to do it, but it works